# debugging failed ajax POST call, type is pending

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I have a javascript file that generates some JSON and makes an AJAX call to a php file that writes and creates the JSON file.  Everything has been working well until I started generating pretty big JSON files.  Currently, I have a 9mb json file and I know it is structured correctly because when I print it out using console.log and manually put into a file, it works.

However, the Ajax call fails to succeed.  I have tried a normal XHR call and jQuery Ajax, both fail and do not provide much information.  I tried in Chrome and Firefox.  Looking at Developer Tools, the status text says (failed) and type says pending.  No status code appears and all I have is statusText: "error" in Ajax error callback.  I tried messing around with timeout and synchronous calls but nothing seems to work/

Any ideas on how I can debug further?

**Code Sample**

```
var name = "test.json";
var json = '{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "bbox": [
        1.4137153625488281,
        42.4288330078125,
        1.7842082977294922,
        42.652313232421875
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "bbox": [
                1.4137153625488281,
                42.4288330078125,
                1.7842082977294922,
                42.652313232421875
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            1.5753068923950195,
                            42.6473388671875
                        ],
                        [
                            1.5828666687011719,
                            42.63543701171875
                        ],
                        [
                            1.5753068923950195,
                            42.6473388671875
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "ID_0": "6",
                "ISO": "AND",
                "NAME_ENGLI": "Andorra",
                "NAME_OBSOL": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}';



$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"log.php",
        data: { data: json, file: name },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error:function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
});
```

This is log.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
$file = $_POST['file'];
$data = str_replace("\\", "", $_POST['data']);

file_put_contents($file, $data);
exit();
}
```

**My main question is this, when AJAX fails, how do you debug better?** My error callback here does not provide any good information.  I tried looking at net-internals in chrome but I can't find much there.  Any ideas?

Perhaps this is a Server Side problem.  When I look at Chrome net-internals I see that processing a smaller JSON (length = 121664) makes a successful POST request and net-internals show HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS but the large JSON (length = 7036490) give me --> net_error = -324 (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) instead of response headers.  I did not see a timeout information in the phpinfo though...

Comment: Please post a sample of the code. Are you using a callback in the js?

Comment: Perhaps the response is larger than that allowed by the server.

Comment: Just type the URL into a browser and see if the server responds. If it does, your problem is on the client. If not, it's on the server.

Comment: put `php_value post_max_size 100M` into your .htaccess file (or change directly in php.ini) and test again, maybe it's just a POST size limit

Comment: I checked phpinfo and post_max_size is set to 32MB which is plenty. This is not a server problem, the client has the error.  Everything works when I generate a JSON file that is not too big.  The big JSON file is also valid, so it should work, but does not.

Comment: @iweczek, so you can type the url into a browser and get a large response from the server?

Comment: @JonathanM, I posted the code for log.php, as you can see it would not give me any response with a GET request, when I open it in a browser it shows a blank screen and the status code is 200.  It works fine, the problem is on the client.

Comment: is a big data received by server and written to your log file?

Comment: @iweczek, you might consider modifying `log.php` to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`. That way it can respond to both POSTs and GETs. Just looking at `log.php` there is no response to the client there. What are you expecting to receive back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

First, check your error logs on the server side.
Try increasing `maxRequestLength` setting in PHP, if the request takes to long to handle.

If it's a client side problem your best bet to get it to work cross browser would be to split your post on the client side and posting it in several parts. On the server side you could save it in a temporary file for instance.

Comment: It is a client side problem, and yes, splitting the post would work, but I would like to debug what fails in the large Ajax request.  The question is how.